# bootbox giving DOM selection trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bootbox

I wanted to use better confirm dialog box, so I decided to use bootbox, however, it is giving me trouble selecting parents element which is very essential for me. Previously, my onclick function parameter was 'this', however, I have to remove it as after using bootbox as 'this' would return bootbox generated dynamic parents which I don't need. My onclick function is:

```
<tr class="live" closestmatch="" matcheswith="" pid="267915" xtid="">
<td tag="_ACTIONS">
<div class=""> 
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel-267915">
    <li>
       <a class="deletebtn" onclick="bootbox.confirm('Delete the record?', function (result) { if (result) { xlist.Delete('a.deletebtn'); }});">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete row
            </a>
    </li>
```

Previously, before using bootbox, I used to have 'this' as parameter for my javascript function `xlist.Delete(this)`, which would then return the corresponding 'a' tag and I could access the 'id' of the concerned row and would pass the id(here pid) to an ajax call for the delete operation.

However, now I cannot include 'this' keyword as it will return bootbox parents elements. But passing 'a.deleteBtn' will select all the rows and will delete the last record if I use 'parents' keyword and delete first record if I use 'closest' keyword when accessing the parents element. My delete method (Delete is a part of xlist):

```
    Delete: function(ele) {
    var row = $(ele).parents('tr'); 
    var pid = row.attr('pid');
    $.post('DeleteRow?pid=' + pid + '&datatype=' + $('#DataType').val(), function (data, text, xhr) {
            $('tr.live[pid=' + data + ']').remove();                

        });
    },
```

How do I select the row that I am doing to delete? I thought about adding a class f. ex., 'selected' whenever I choose 'delete' option from the dropdown but this would add 'selected' class to all rows. Any help in this regard will be appreciated, feel free to ask if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind `click` event on class `.deletebtn` like,

```
<tr class="live" closestmatch="" matcheswith="" pid="267915" xtid="">
<td tag="_ACTIONS">
<div class=""> 
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel-267915">
    <li>
       <a class="deletebtn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete row
       </a>
    </li>
....
```

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) to bind click event on delete button and don't pass all `a.deletebtn` in `Delete` function, just you need to pass the current clicked anchor element like,

```
$('.deletebtn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    vat that = this;
    bootbox.confirm('Delete the record?', function (result) { 
       if (result) {
           xlist.Delete(that); // pass 'that' instead of passing all 'a.deletebtn'
       }
    });
});
```

One more thing, use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) instead of using [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents) in `Delete` function. So that it is sure that it will give the closest `tr` not all the parents encountered in hierarchy.

```
Delete: function(ele) {
   var row = $(ele).closest('tr');  // use closest in place of parents here
   var pid = row.attr('pid');
   // bla bla bla
},
```

Comment: Your suggestion works! Thanks and appreciate for your time. If you think my question worth something, please upvote.